# Google search result shows error 403

Tags: html, apache, .htaccess, http-status-code-403

when i search my website in Google search, and click on link, Google shows error

> "403. That’s an error. Your client does not have permission to get URL
>   /interstitial?   url=http://www.domain.com/ from this server.
>   That’s all we know."

Here My .htaccess file code:

```
# -FrontPage-

IndexIgnore .htaccess */.??* *~ *# */HEADER* */README* */_vti*

<Limit GET POST>
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from all
</Limit>
<Limit PUT DELETE>
order deny,allow
deny from all
</Limit>
AuthName meezaneadel.com
AuthUserFile /home/meezane/public_html/_vti_pvt/service.pwd
AuthGroupFile /home/meezane/public_html/_vti_pvt/service.grp
```

Answer (score 0):

The `PUT`, `DELETE` section is unnecessary unless your server has scripts configured to service such requests. The `GET`, `POST` section is also unnecessary because you basically do not want to prevent access to anyone.

So, just remove the two sections and try accessing your site again.

Comment: Hello, your mean i can remove <Limit GET POST> , <Limit PUT DELETE> section ?

Comment: Yes, considering you do not want to restrict access, they do not serve any real purpose and should be removed.